# ASP.Net MVC Web Application - Bootstrap update to version 5

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5

I updated bootstrap from v3.4.1 to 5.1.3 and at start I had the same problem as OP from this [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjbhi.jpg). Which I resolved thx to answers.
And now when I click on hamburger icon Navbar expands, and then it doesn't want to shrink when I click on it again.

I copied Navbar example from bootstrap site.

My _Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container body-content">
        <br />
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And my BundleConfig

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
```

[image]

Comment: (1) For sure only 5.1.3 CSS and JS library loaded and 3.4.1 library is not loaded in your html? (2) Have you tried creating just a vanilla bootstrap page and slowly add your original page elements into the vanilla page to determine when it breaks?

Comment: Hi, only bootstrap 5.1.3 is loaded

Comment: (2) Have you tried creating just a vanilla bootstrap page and slowly add your original page elements into the vanilla page to determine when it breaks?

Comment: (3) Yes I did, and I cant find any errors. It works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my BoundleConfig.cs was wrong. This is correct

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"
                      ));

            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
```

And so was my head tag in _Layout.cshtml. This is correct

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

Comment: Hnmmm hamburger menu is still wonky for me, is there something else you fixed but didn't post in your answer?

Comment: Hi did you fix it? Is it still bothering you?